# Java EE 7 CDI Manual Instantiation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

I have a Class with fields annotated with @Inject. I instantiate the Class using reflection, but I want the CDI to inject instances to do the Class instance fields. Is there a way of doing it?

```
Object myInstanceWithDependecies = Class.forName(“com.package.MyClass").newInstance();
CDI.injectAll(myInstanceWithDependecies);//This is what i want
```

Does someone know how to do this? I would appreciate if there was a way of doing it without scanning each field using reflection.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: CDI really does have documentation, at which point you would read about producer methods: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjdid.html .

Comment: Do you want this to write JUnit Tests or for other reason?

Comment: I do know it has a documentation, I have been there and i HAVE READ IT. The problem is that you aren't understanding my problem. I know about producer methods and fields. They don't help me solve my problem. I'm instantiating the class by myself. Cant you see that the class I'm instantiating is dynamic? I need a way of invoking the CDI and tell it to do the Injection on my Object Instance.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22928977/1346996) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This gets the Job done

> SomeBean bean = CDI.current().select(SomeBean.class).get();

Answer (score 0):

This link describes how to use OpenWebBeans in a JavaSE Application:

http://openwebbeans.apache.org/owbsetup_se.html

If you want use it for Unit Tests, i would recommend to use Arquillian:

http://arquillian.org

Answer (score 0):

In order to have CDI dependencies resolved, your instance of `com.package.MyClass` has to be a managed bean (instantiated by the container), if not it is not possible to let the container resolve its dependencies.

To solve your problem you could do a programmatic lookup without creating the instance yourself:

```
CDI.current().select(Class.forName("com.package.MyClass")).get() 
//remember to check for ambiguous or unsatisfied dependency
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `com.package.MyClass` is not managed by CDI, it is not possible by standard CDI to inject the dependencies as pointed out by others.

However, all infrastructure is available. DeltaSpike offers the functionality you are looking for. It is also possible to use this code fragment (no dependencies on other DeltaSpike code) without including DeltaSpike.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T injectFields(T instance) {
    if (instance == null) {
        return null;
    }
    BeanManager beanManager = CDI.current().getBeanManager();
    CreationalContext<T> creationalContext = beanManager.createCreationalContext(null);
    AnnotatedType<T> annotatedType =
        beanManager.createAnnotatedType((Class<T>) instance.getClass());
    InjectionTarget<T> injectionTarget = beanManager.createInjectionTarget(annotatedType);
    injectionTarget.inject(instance, creationalContext);
    return instance;
}
```